# How to remove Header and Footer from the second page of the PDF report of Sale order, Invoice, Purchase Order, Bill, etc. In Odoo 12v

Tags: python, pdf, odoo, odoo-12

I want to remove the header and footer(Company Logo and Company Details) from the second page of the to last page PDF report expect. Only first page Contains Logo and Company details the second page does not contain any Logo and company details. I want these changes in my Sale order pdf report template, Purchase Order pdf report template, Invoice pdf report template, Bill pdf report template.

Currently, I am using Odoo 12, 
OS is ubuntu 16.04.

Please suggest me the solution to this problem. Hope I was clear enough.

[image: My report]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Sale Report is now a QWEB(HTML) report, not an RML,

you can modify in setting->Actions->Reports, search for 'Quotation' select the sale.order one, there you can:

change the report type to HTML, print a quotation/sale, and edit it with the website editor.
click in Search associated QWEB views, select the report_saleorder_document, and edit it.
change it via the custom module.

for more info go to the official documentation: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/reports.html

Comment: In the documentation, not find any clue how to resolve the issue. Please reply if you have any other idea regarding this.

Comment: you can make your own header footer and apply it on first page

Comment: I  make my own header and footer but when it is creating a new page it also put header and footer in that. I want my header and footer in my first page not on the second page.